# preserving original df index while doing groupby, transform and explode

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I have an issue with keeping indices after group by. I have a use case that requires a groupby, then I want to feed the values in each group to a function, input is a list and the function returns a list. The next step is to explode the list and redistribute the updated values.

However, I can't join this new df back to the original one since the indices are different. Is there a way to preserve the indices and use them to reshuffle df1 according to the original index positions?

```
def modify_list(values):
    modified_values = []
    for i in range(len(values)):
        if i != 0 and values[i] > 6:
            modified_values.append(0)
        else:
            modified_values.append(values[i])
    return modified_values

df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
                   'class':['s','s', 'l', 'me', 'mi', 'me', 'mi', 'l', 'ml'],
                   'value':[0.25, 0.05, 0.34, 0.15, 0.25, 0.45, 0.25, 0.25, 0.01]}
              )

df1 = df.groupby('group')['value'].agg(list).transform(modify_list).explode().reset_index().rename(columns={'value':'value2'})
```

If I merge df1 and df here, the values will lose there relation to the class feature.

Comment: If this is your actual calculation, you don't need a groupby. You can just do: `df['value2'] = df['value'].mask(df.duplicated('group') & df['value'].gt(6), 0)`. I.e. you check if a value in column "group" is the first of its kind and if value in column "value" > 6. If *not*, you keep the value from "value", else you select `0`.

Comment: It's not, this is a made up example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using transform directly like this:

```py
df['value_modified'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform(lambda x: modify_list(x.tolist()))
```

Comment: Why does using the lambda function produce a different result?

Comment: I only used lambda to get the list directly using .tolist(), since your functions requires a list. Using transform ensures you keep the original order.